# AsyncTask, Insert, Select wrong order of execution in Android

Tags: android, database, select, android-asynctask, insert

Hee guys,

I'm currently debugging an Application which retreives certain data from a database, it wil display it afterwards in a listview. However it uses an extra method to sort these results on date and display this in a Category called "Gesorteerd op datum" and this contains subcategorys with the months in it. Example:

[Link screenshot because i miss 1 reputation to upload a image.](http://i888.photobucket.com/albums/ac86/jordisipkens/Screenshot_2014-10-29-10-25-24_zps6470cd9d.png)

As you can see the opened part is static, i'm using a function to select all the data between a certain time period and then sort these over months and insert these back into the database to make things as dynamic as possible(I'm also inserting the custom made "Gesorteerd op Datum" and the months). However when first using this App and you open this fragment the "Gesorteerd on Datum" part is completely missing. However by pressing back and then go in again its there.

So the problem is that the inserts takes longer to complete then the function to select and display all the list items. I tried fixing this by using 2 Asynctasks.

First asynctask : DoInBackground function inserts the "Gesorteerd op datum" and al submonths, this uses a listener so that it wont do the next thing until it completes. Then the onPostExecute runs a function that displays the categorys. However here it already goes wrong because the "gesorteerd op datum" isn't added in the Array that later is used to display the listview.

Second Asynctask : DoInBackground uses a functions that gets and sorts the events by date and inserts them afterwards. Then the onPostexecute gets all the events including the "gesorteerd op datum" events and displays them in the listview below. as said above it doesn't do what it should do.

Anyone knows where it goes wrong? Because after reading the Asynctask documentation, I understand it shouldn't load the categorys after the first insert is done. But it still does load them to early.

```
/*
 * Insert Static categories into database.
 * Easier to manipulate and prevents unnecessary code.
 */
class Static extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{     
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        insertStaticData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        getAllStaticData(); 
        new async().execute();
    }
}

/*
 * Insert Static categories into database.
 * Easier to manipulate and prevents unnecessary code.
 */
class async extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{      

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        toggleLoadingView(mLoading, mExpandableListView, mRootView, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (sCurrentRadius != 0 && mLastLocation != null) {
            loadCursor(mLastLocation, sCurrentRadius); 
        } else{
            loadCursor();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        getAllDynamicData();
    }
}
```

These are my Asyncs edited after a suggestion from below. They show them now, but it won't show all the months that it should show. When I reload it shows them.

Comment: Why not put the selecting of data in the onPostExecute of the initial AsyncTask, that way you know the thread has finished, before running your select?

Comment: How do you mean? Because my initial one first creates the static categorys and inserts them. Then in the onPostExecute it gets only the Categorys. After that I start a second Async to get and sort the events on date and then in the onPostExecute i display the events in the categorys.

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried it but then it wont display at all.

Comment: I got a dirty solution at this moment, is use a handler to make a delay of 2 second before executing the second Async. This way the inserts have time to finish before the code continues. However this makes the app a bit slower and I hope someone will help me find a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty solution :

Make a handler and post delay for X seconds so the inserts will be done. The X might variate from how much inserting and stuff you'll have to do.

```
  /*
   * Run the Async and then after a delay load the listview needed. 
   */
  new Static().execute();

  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
         public void run() {
            if (sCurrentRadius != 0 && mLastLocation != null) {
                loadCursor(mLastLocation, sCurrentRadius); 
            } else{
                loadCursor();
            }
        }
    }, 4000);

/*
     * Insert Static categories into database.
     * Easier to manipulate and prevents unnecessary code.
     */
    class Static extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{     

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            toggleLoadingView(mLoading, mExpandableListView, mRootView, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            insertStaticData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
        {
            getAllStaticData();
        }
    }
```